# Reverse engineering of hash functions

Tags: encryption, hash

I have an unknown process that gets some vars and returns an 8byte hash.
I'm sure which vars it gets and I'm sure these are all the variable parts of the input. 
I can query this process when and how I want then I have many and many cases of input and output couples.

My question is, is it mathematically  possible to find the hashing function?

Comment: Do you have the binary file? If so, disassemble it.

Comment: No, unfortunately this is a smartcard... not a library.

Answer (score 2):

You can try various [hash algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions) with various inputs and hope to get lucky. There aren't all that many commonly used hash functions. Being the hash is only 64 bits, it's probably only a portion of the full hash. When you shorten a hash, you typically just grab the first or last N bits, though some dev may have gotten creative and grabbed only the odd bits or something.

That said, I suspect that you will not find a match. Smartcards generally have a secret that is embedded in them that cannot be extracted (excluding techniques used on poorly designed/manufactured chips that involve [acid baths and x-rays and such](http://home.deib.polimi.it/zanero/papers/scsecurity.pdf)). This secret is then used in cryptographic operations (eg: [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) or [digital signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature)) which are performed on the card. Being that the secret is only known to the card (in the case of asymmetric crypto) or the card and card issuer (in the case of symmetric crypto), an attacker cannot reproduce the cryptographic operation. So, while you are sure you know what the input is to the card, it is likely that the input to the crypto operation is a combination of those inputs *and* the unobtainable secret that is built into the chip.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. About the secret, if I send the input vars and the output to the smartcard supplier they can say to me if the hash is good using a webservice call (http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/ValidatorWeb/ValidatorServer#ValidateSeal). Then I think there is not a secret in the card, otherwise the supplier store all secrets in a database to check hash.... Surely this is not an easy attemp.

Comment: Interesting @Tobia. Do you somehow associate a serial number for the smartcard or an account number with the call? If that's the case then they may be looking up the account info to get info about the secret. And they don't need to store the secret if they are using [assymectric crypto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography); all they need is the public key. The only copy (only --> secure) of the private key may be on the card.

Answer (score 0):

Each hashing algorithm (that is standardized; not including the 'roll-your-own' solutions) uses specific lengths and some implement specific characteristics;

For example; md5 hashes are 128 bits, 32 characters in length.

For a full comparison see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_cryptographic_hash_functions) as this should substantially shrink your focus.